# Page numbering in the HTML files using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

Please let me know how to display the page numbers in the generated HTML files using XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Use can use like

fo:page-sequence master-reference="id-1" in you xslt